# PHP system/exec command not working properly

Tags: php, windows, command-line

This is my code:

```
$js = SPLoginEngage();
$data = getSilverpopReport($js,'09/01/2012');
$d1 = explode('<FILE_PATH>',$data);
$d2 = explode('</FILE_PATH>',$d1[1]);
sleep(30);
exec('CMD /C run.bat "/download/' . $d2[0] . '"');
```

run.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
start /b "" "C:\Program files\WinSCP\winscp.exe" "SFTP" /command "get "%1"" exit
```

When I run the script I get this returned: `CMD /C run.bat "/download/Raw Recipient Data Export Sep 13 2012 08-07-54 AM 1371.zip"`

It's supposed to start a download for a file, but nothing happens.

If I take that output and put it in CMD it works fine.

Note: Running Windows 7 (32bit)

Comment: may I ask, what speaks against the browser doing the download for you? (this is very limited to local client settings for a server hosted script language)

Comment: this could be a cli script intended to run locally too...

Comment: @Najzero The file is hosted on a remote SFTP, the browser cannot perform the download.

Comment: then let the server pull the files for ( you http://php.net/manual/de/function.ssh2-sftp.php ) - just a suggestion, for large files its evil ;-)

Comment: @Najzero, I couldn't get that library to work on my PC for some reason, that's why I'm using this external app

Answer (score 0):

why are you calling CMD in your exec argument? isn't that what exec should do anyways?

Also you are not doing anything with the result of the exec.. how do you know if it has executed the command?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Tried without it as well and it didn't work. From what I understand exec/system should return the command it executed if execution succeeded and 'false' if failed. Since I'm getting the command line returned I'm guessing it succeeded but the file is not being downloaded

Comment: try adding an output argument to the exec call and var_dump it's content after it's done.. maybe that'll tell you more